# when I give overflow auto on the child of flex item which has flex-1, overflow auto doesn't work

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

```
<div class="FLEX-CONTAINER flex overflow-hidden">
  <div class="SIDE-BAR h-96 w-4 flex-shrink-0 bg-yellow-300"></div>
  <div class="CONTENT flex-1 bg-green-500">
    <div class="WRAPPER w-full max-w-full overflow-auto">
      <div class="TOO-LONG-CONTENT h-10 w-[2000px] bg-red-600"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so here's my code ( using tailwind ). I'm curious why overflow-auto works when I give overflow-auto to CONTENT, but doesn't work when I give it to WRAPPER?

I thought WRAPPER's width is 100% and it has same width with CONTENT. so if overflow-auto on CONTENT works then overflow-auto on WRAPPER has to work either. but actually it's not.
I want to know what causes the difference.